# Can't authorize with Spotify API

Tags: api, spotify

I try to authorize through Spotify API (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) and my code is:

```
<a href="">Spotify link</a>
```

But instead of redirect me to my page it says:

[image]

I tried to delete app from "My applications" tab on developer.spotify.com and create a new one with new client id and it is no different. I log in to Spotify with my Facebook account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. You have to go to your application settings and enter your URL into "Redirect URLs" and it will work. I wonder why it isn't included in documentation.

Comment: It is - see here: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/ Specifically, "This URI needs to have been entered in the Redirect URI whitelist that you specified when you registered your application".